# in iphone how to write code for radio button

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

while i am doing program i got dbt how to write the code for radio button

Comment: What exactly your doubts are about?

Comment: in a view i want to add two radio buttons one is solved and another is pendding.if one button click then other must be withdraw.

Comment: I am not very sure how the people making vote down now for long back finished conversation question. This question was posted long back but now I got vote down. Is this the way our community encouraging old questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ranjeet says, there is no radio button.
You can used segmented control, switch or button depending on the aim.

Answer (score 0):

iphone does not support radiobutton...
I mean this feature has not present here...

You have to make your tricks(alternates)...
like show and hide  images...and some more